# Writing API documentation with Swagger OpenAPI 3

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, openapi

I'm trying to write API documentation with Swagger OpenAPI 3

the most important part , is to write a schema for the requestBody

check the below example

```
requestBody: {
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: {'x-ts-type': {x: String}},
        },
      },
    },
```

the result is empty Schema , it does not work ,
where's the issue ?

Comment: There's no `x-ts-type` keyword in the [OpenAPI 3.0 Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md). What kind of schema are you trying to describe? A simple string, or an object with a string property, or something else?

Comment: See if this helps: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Comment: @Helen , object

Comment: How does this object look like? Please post an example (sample JSON/XML/etc.)

Comment: @Helen , FYI , I use loopback 4 as a framework ,
any object for exampel {userId : number , name : string}

Comment: I do not see a problem with your custom property. If a standard OpenAPI parser encounters such a property, it will ignore it because it’s prefixed with x-.
https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-9-extending-the-openapi-specification/